# Why does Chromium say every page has insecure content?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, https, chromium

A lot of people seem to be having this problem, and few are getting concrete answers.

Why does Chromium say every page has insecure content?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Just a quick note: when you post your answer, you might also want to work on the question a bit, removing the commentary about answering your own question and adding some details about the actual problem, maybe also a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the problem was being caused by the extension incognito switcher, and uninstalling it resolved things. There are posts around the internet saying that particular extension has been "hacked".

Here's how I identified the problem extension:

First, on a page that showed the warning, I looked at the console (ctrl-shift-i), and searched for the warning about insecure content. The originating page was http://www.v-tool.com/switcher/stats.js.

I searched for the file referring to this page using the following command:

`grep -R http://www.v-tool.com/switcher/stats.js ~/.config/chromium/`

After examining the matching files, it was pretty easy to find the guilty extension.